# Definite Integral with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I am supposed to evaluate the integral with respect to parameter:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2p}}dx$$

What I did was:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2p}}dx\left\{\begin{matrix}
\left [ \frac{x^{-2p+1}}{-2p+1}\right ]_{0}^{1}, p\neq \frac{1}{2}\\ 
\left [ ln(x) \right ]_{0}^{1},p=\frac{1}{2}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

And then:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2p}}dx\left\{\begin{matrix}
\infty , 0< p\leq \frac{1}{2}\\ 
\\\frac{1}{-2p+1},\frac{1}{2}< p\leq 1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is that correct? I am aksing, because I do now know if I understand it correctly

Comment: No. For $p<1/2$ the integral is finite.

Comment: @amsmath thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\left [ \frac{x^{-2p+1}}{-2p+1}\right ]_{0}^{1}=\frac1{1-2p}\left [ \frac1{x^{2p-1}}\right ]_{0}^{1} = \infty$$

for $2p-1>0 \implies p>\frac12$ and therefore

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{2p}}dx=\begin{cases}
\infty , \quad p\ge \frac{1}{2}\\ 
\\\frac{1}{-2p+1},\quad 0\le p<\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Omg, yes I switched it.. thanks

Comment: @Shelley You are welcome! Bye